# How to understand ({ (void)(x), 0; })?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

In the linux kernel(v6.0) source code `/kernel/sched/sched.h`, I found a macro:

```
#define SCHED_WARN_ON(x)      ({ (void)(x), 0; })
```

My question is that how to understand the expression `({ (void)(x), 0; })`. In my knowledge, the return value of that expression is `0`. The `(void)(x)` part seems neglectable here, as the return value of `{ (void)(x), 0; }` always depends on `, 0; }` part, which returns `0`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `(void)` is used to suppress warnings about not using the return value of `x`

Comment: I got you, but what confuses me is more about the whole part of ```({ (void)(x), 0; })```, as I think the return value of the code block is always ```0```.

Comment: @nakeydoln yes, it is always `0`. What's the problem with that?

Comment: @Marco Bonelli I just wonder then what is the ```x``` for? As I first see this macro function there is some boolean operation in it like ```SCHED_WARN_ON( [boolean operation] ).```

Comment: It's not the only definition of the macro. It's a version for when a flag (`CONFIG_SCHED_DEBUG`) requests no diagnostics. The version that warns, actually does something with `x`. This version simply suppresses all warnings.

Comment: The code in `(x)` will be executed for its side effects. E.g. `SCHED_WARN_ON(printf("some message"))`